# Elasticsearch not accessible over internet through ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, ip

We are facing issues while accessing elasticsearch over ip address on internet in AWS Windows environment.

I have tried various options of modifying network.host parameter and network.bind_host parameter, without any luck.

There are no errors shown just "page not found" is displayed.

Can you provide with the valid elasticsearch.yml file?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what the problem you having is? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I am trying to access ElasticSearch of an AWS machine (machine 1) in an other AWS machine (machine 2). Trying to access the Elastic Search using machine 1 ip address. There are no errors shown just "page not found" is displayed.

Comment: Why don't you show your own elasticsearch.yml?